# How to create a shared network for docker containers to communicate as "localhost" (with docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

#### Overview & Goal:

I have a docker-compose configuration for running multiple services and one of the features I'm trying to implement requires that the containers can refer to each other as `localhost`.

#### What I've tried:

I attempted using `network_mode: host` which did the job as far as my testing showed, but wouldn't work for team members that have MacOS.

I also tried using network aliases. In the example I fail to `wget localhost:6000` from the `service_1` container

```yaml
services:

  service_1:
    #other attributes
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      shared_net:
        aliases:
          - localhost

  service_2:
    #other attributes
    ports:
      - 6000:6000
    networks:
      shared_net:
        aliases:
          - localhost

networks:
  shared_net:
```

Many thanks

Comment: Had you tried using `wget service_2:6000` from `service_1` container?`

Comment: Why is the only possible host name `localhost`?  That seems like it'd make it impossible to run the code in any sort of clustered or containerized environment.  If that's really your requirement, running the services "on the host" in a virtual machine is a little better match than Docker.